# How to determine the integral limits of continuous wavelet transform?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, wavelets

Now I have one function $f(x)$, and its support interval is $x\in[T_0,T_1]$. The support interval of the mother wavelet $\psi(x)$ is $x\in[-\Delta,+\Delta]$. And we also know that the continuous wavelet transform is
$$
W(a,b) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)\Psi(\frac{t-b}{a})\text{d}t
$$

According to the formula above, It seems like you need to do the integration from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. However, we don't have to do it since that $f(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are compact support. So **my question** is How do we determine the appropriate integral limits?

- Here is my attempt:

According to "the support interval of the mother wavelet $\psi(x)$ is $x\in[-\Delta,+\Delta]$", we know that
$$
-\Delta\leq\frac{t-b}{a}\leq\Delta\, \,\Rightarrow \, \, b-a\Delta\leq t \leq b+a\Delta
$$

And because that the support interval of $f(t)$ is $[T_0,T_1]$ , we have
$$
T_0\leq t \leq T_1
$$

But I don't know how what I should do next. Whether could we determine the integral limits by these two inequalities above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your integration limits should just be the intersection of the intervals you specified. That is, the product $f(t)\Psi\left(\frac{t-b}{a}\right)$ is zero whenever
$$t\notin A \triangleq\left([b−aΔ, b+aΔ]\bigcap[T_0, T_1]\right)$$
So
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)\Psi\left(\frac{t-b}{a}\right)dt
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{\min A}^{\max A}f(t)\Psi\left(\frac{t-b}{a}\right)dt
$$
Example: For Δ=10, a=1, b=2, $T_0=-3$, $T_1=35$, $\min A=-3$ and $\max A=12$